# <img src="x" onerror="alert(\"hello\")" />) escaping quote is illegal?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to play around with escape character.

```
<img src="x" onerror=alert('hello'); />

<img src="x" onerror="alert(\"hello\")" />
```

The 2nd one produces `illegal character` in the dev console. Why? Why can't I use the escape character?

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h7nnk/1/

Answer (score 10):

Because `\` is not an escape character in HTML.

```
<img src="x" onerror="alert(&quot;hello&quot;)" />
```

Or, as per @mplungjan's comment:

```
<img src="x" onerror="alert('hello')" />
```

Or, better still:

```
<img src="x" id="derp" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('derp').addEventListener("error",function() {
        alert('hello');
    },false);
</script>
```